# Тренировочные данные для нейронной сети полостью занимают оперативную память компьютера

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Я пытаюсь написать нейронную сеть для задачи классификации объектов по картинке. На вход сеть принимает 250 000 значений rbg, по итогу получается 750 000 элементов для одной картинки. Я создаю массив, куда хотелось бы заполнить около 20 000 примеров (значений пикселей для 20 000 картинок). Разумеется, оперативной памяти для создания такого массива не хватает.

Вопрос: как в такой ситуации лучше организовать обучение?

Стоит отметить, что, если последовательно обучать нейронную сеть на каждой картинке отдельно, то процесс занимает слишком много времени, так как для каждого прохода через все тренировочные данные необходимо открывать картинку и конвертировать ее в массив с пикселями.

Answer (score 3):

Все более менее серьезные модели, основанные на НС (нейронных сетях), обучаются  батчами, т.е. модель обучается кусками (батчами). В каждой эпохе обучения модель проходит через все экземпляры обучающей выборки кусками / батчами по `batch_size` экземпляров.

Вот [пример того как подать картинки на вход НС при помощи keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html):

```
batch_size = 16

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# this is a generator that will read pictures found in
# subfolers of 'data/train', and indefinitely generate
# batches of augmented image data
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(150, 150),  # all images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')  # since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels

# this is a similar generator, for validation data
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
```

Comment: Да, вот это самый правильный подход

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: batch еще называется когда там градиент к куску применяется.

Comment: @ILEM, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Надо уменьшить размер выборки. 20к картинок - это очень много, сеть может обучиться и на 2к. Чтобы не переобучилась, надо разделить эти 2к на данные для обучения и теста. Можно также написать скрипт, который будет разбивать 20к на данные по 2к, а потом обучать на этих 2к. Но если у вас эпох больше одной-двух, то после обучения на первых 2к вы увидите результат выше 90% точности

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: надо маленьким картинками обучать.